# Move all files in subfolder with same extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to move all images files in my project into one folder called `texture`.
A lot of subfolder including the images and I have no time for move every single one.
I tried this:

```
@echo off
cd E:\x\
move /s *.dds Textures
```

It didn't work, then I tried this one it didn't work too!

```
forfiles /S /M *.dds /C "cmd /c move @file texture"
```

Any solution?

Comment: [`move`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html) does not support an `/S` switch!

Comment: You would end up with a cyclical copy errors with the logic you are trying to use. `MOVE` and `FORFILES` are the wrong tools to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
md "d:\all snaps"
cd /d "d:\vacation snaps\2016"
for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "d:\all snaps\"
```

This recursively copies all files in the d:\vacation snaps\2016\ folder to the d:\all snaps\ folder. To move the files, replace copy with move

If a file of the same name exists in the destination, you’ll be asked if you want to overwrite or skip the file.

Note: It’s always safe to include the trailing backslash () after the destination folder path, as in the above example. Because, without the trailing slash, if the destination path is missing and you run the command, then the files in the folder and subfolders are copied and combined into one single file named all snaps to D:\ drive.

Comment: 1) This will not execute successfully in a Windows .BAT which is what the user tagged their question with. 2) The user specifically gave an example of moving the files into a subfolder of their source directory. Your example is using two completely different folder structures.