# Recursive subfolders and move all files with extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

A couple of hours ago I started on what I thought was going to be an easy task.  I want to move all files with an .eking extension in a directory, and subfolders of that directory, and subfolders of those subfolders, and so on.  I found possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68589679/move-all-files-in-subfolder-with-same-extension), but it didn't traverse subfolders.

Here is my windows batch file code which only works for the top level folder (not subfolders).  Run in an administrative command prompt.

```
md "c:\eking"
cd /d "c:\temp\"
for /r %d in (*.eking) do move "%d" "c:\eking\"
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), which can also move files when specifying the `/MOV` (or `/MOVE`) option…

Comment: The code you have posted does not work only in the top level folder. It is written to move all files within the `C:\temp` tree and with an extension `.eking` to the directroy `C:\eking`, as long as that directory was created successfully, and the end user has permissions to access it. However, if what you've posted is a batch-file, as opposed to commands directly entered in cmd, you need to change `%d` to `%%d`, as specifically mentioned in the usage information for the command, `for /?`

Comment: Agree with comment above - don't reinvent the wheel and just use robocopy.

Comment: @Compo is correct, the revised script works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Compo.  After making the changes you suggested here is the revised script that works.

```
md "c:\eking"
cd /d "c:\temp\"
for /r %%d in (*.eking) do move "%%d" "c:\eking\"
```

Comment: if you're running the above on a mapped drive you have to run as the user with the mapped drive.  Administrator prompt won't see the drives you've mapped as they are user centric.

Comment: Instead of usiing `CD /D "C:\temp"`, you may wish to also try it with `PushD "C:\temp"`, if `C:\temp`, in your real world script is really a network path.

Comment: What will happen if a filename appears in two or more directories?